# Azure DevOps Pipelines and Poetry Dynamic Versioning

Tags: azure-devops, python-poetry

I have a pipeline which builds a Python package and publishes it to Azure Artecfacts.

It all works, but when the pipeline runs it builds a new version of my package with the version "0.0.0". (Recommended default version when using Poetry Dynamic Versioning)

When I run "poetry build" locally, I get what I would consider a proper version based on the last tag e.g. my-wonderful-package-0.1.1.post8.dev0+2321b98.tar.gz

Here are the most important parts of my pipeline:

```
 - task: UsePythonVersion@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '3.8'
    addToPath: true
    architecture: 'x64'

- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: |
      curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 -
      export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.poetry/bin
  displayName: 'Install poetry'

- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: echo "##vso[task.prependpath]$HOME/.poetry/bin"
  displayName: Add poetry to PATH

- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: |
      poetry install --no-root
  displayName: 'Install Poetry dependencies'

- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: Build Artifacts
  inputs:
    script: |
      echo Building distribution package
      poetry self add "poetry-dynamic-versioning[plugin]"
      poetry build
```

Also here is the dynamic settings from my pyproject.toml:

```
[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core", "poetry-dynamic-versioning"]
build-backend = "poetry_dynamic_versioning.backend"

[[tool.poetry.source]]
(info about my feed)

[tool.poetry-dynamic-versioning]
enable = true
vcs = "git"
style= "pep440"
```

Should I not expect poetry build to behave the same way when building locally vs on the build agent? Am I missing something fundamental about how Poetry Dynamic Versioning works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce the similar issue in my pipeline with the same settings in pyproject.toml file.

[image]

The cause of the issue could be related to the fetch depth of the Pipeline repo.

By default, the Shallow fetch of the pipeline repo is 1 by default.

You can try to set the **fetchDepth** to **0** in YAML Pipeline.

For example:

```
steps:
- checkout: self
  fetchDepth: 0
  
- task: UsePythonVersion@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '3.8'
    addToPath: true
    architecture: 'x64'

- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: |
      curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 -
      export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.poetry/bin
  displayName: 'Install poetry'
 ...
```

Or you can navigate to **YAML Pipeline -> ... -> Triggers -> YAML -> Get sources -> Shallow fetch**.  You can unselect the option.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I can confirm this works, and it also clarifies why the correct version wasn't being picked up.